# Disable Background drawing in JFrame in order to properly display Aero (DWM) effects

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jna, dwm

I'm having problems using the DWM functionality of Windows Vista/7 on Java windows. I want to make the background of my frame use the Aero style. The Windows API to do so is provide by the function `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` in the `dwmapi` library. I've managed to call the procedure properly via JNA, and it does what it is supposed to do (You can see that for example when resizing the frame, before the next repaint you see the proper aero effects in the area not yet painted, see the attached image).

But somewhere (I can't figure out where) a background is painted over the Aero effect and the effect is lost.

What I have already tried:

- Using a custom `ContentPane` with opacity set to `false`
- Setting the opacity of the `LayeredPane` and the `RootPane` to false
- Using a `Frame` instead of a `JFrame`
- Set the background color of the `JFrame`/`ContentPane` to black/fully transparent
- Use `setLayersOpaque` and a custom variant thereof, see first answer for more details

So far I could not succeed removing that background. Is it a limitation of AWT/Swing? How can I remove that background or use the Aero effect properly?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

## Screenshot

Here a screenshot of a frame without any contents, having set the opacity of the RootPane, LayeredPane and ContentPane to false. I did it quickly while resizing. You see that the effect is properly applied to the area Java did not yet paint on.

http://i55.tinypic.com/v614qo.png (As a new user I cannot post the image directly...)

## Odd behavior

Upon further investigation I came across the following odd behavior. If the window size is 150x150 or below the contents are displayed transparently. This is very glitchy for normal window components. If you paint directly on the frame by overriding the `paint()` method everything is drawn semi-transparent. Additionally the coordinate system seems to be a little off, it appears as the zero point of the `JFrame` is set to the actual zero point of the window. Thus Swing tries to paint to areas where actually the window border is located, which then of course is not visible.

See this screenshot: http://d-gfx.kognetwork.ch/java_aero_bug.png

## Example code

This is the code I use.

Requires `jna.jar` and `platform.jar`. Available from the JNA homepage.

```
import com.sun.jna.Function;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HRESULT;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class AeroFrame extends JFrame {

    public AeroFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Testlabel");
        label.setOpaque(false);

        add(label);

        pack();

        enableAeroEffect();
    }

    private void enableAeroEffect() {
        NativeLibrary dwmapi = NativeLibrary.getInstance("dwmapi");
        HWND aeroFrameHWND = new HWND(Native.getWindowPointer(this));
        MARGINS margins = new MARGINS();
        margins.cxLeftWidth = -1;
        margins.cxRightWidth = -1;
        margins.cyBottomHeight = -1;
        margins.cyTopHeight = -1;
        //DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(HWND hWnd, MARGINS *pMarInset)
        //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969512%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
        Function extendFrameIntoClientArea = dwmapi.getFunction("DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea");
        HRESULT result = (HRESULT) extendFrameIntoClientArea.invoke(HRESULT.class,
                new Object[] { aeroFrameHWND, margins});
        if(result.intValue()!=0)
            System.err.println("Call to DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea failed.");
    }

    /**
     * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773244%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
     */
    public class MARGINS extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference {
            public int cxLeftWidth;
            public int cxRightWidth;
            public int cyTopHeight;
            public int cyBottomHeight;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new AeroFrame().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you use the Windows look & feel instead of the default Metal?

Comment: I am using the Windows look & feel. But it's the same problem with both the Metal L&F and the Windows L&F. No difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question.

The most obvious answer would be

```
WindowUtils.setWindowOpaque(this, false);
```

That gives you the visual effects you want but unfortunately prevents you from being able to click on the Window!

The second thing I tried was to override the paint() method to perform the same actions that `Window.paint()` does when the `opaque` flag is set to false.  That didn't do anything.

Then I tried using Reflection.  Reflectively setting `Window.opaque` to true gave the same results as using `WindowUtils`.

Finally, I tried adding this to `enableAeroEffect()`:

```
Method m = null;
try {
    m = Window.class.getDeclaredMethod("setLayersOpaque", Component.class, Boolean.TYPE);
    m.setAccessible(true);
    m.invoke(null, this, false);
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    //TODO: handle errors correctly
} finally {
    if ( m != null ) {
        m.setAccessible(false);
    }
}
```

This worked!  The Window still responds properly to mouse events, but the background isn't drawn.  The drawing is a bit glitchy, but should get you on your way.

Obviously it's fragile since it relies on Reflection.  If I were you, I'd take a look at what `Window.setLayersOpaque()` *does*, and try to replicate that in a way that doesn't rely on Reflection.

**Edit**: On inspection of the `setLayersOpaque` method, it really seems to boil down to disabling double-buffering on the transparent components.  Call this method from your `enableAeroEffect()` method and you're on your way:

```
//original source: Sun, java/awt/Window.java, setLayersOpaque(Component, boolean)
private static void setLayersTransparent(JFrame frame) {
    JRootPane root = frame.getRootPane();
    root.setOpaque(false);
    root.setDoubleBuffered(false);

    Container c = root.getContentPane();
    if (c instanceof JComponent) {
        JComponent content = (JComponent) c;
        content.setOpaque(false);
        content.setDoubleBuffered(false);
    }
    frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Comment: `WindowUtils.setWindowOpaque(this, false);` only appears to give the effect. Actually its a glitch, you see that it does not work if you tab to another window and then back to it.
And the `setLayersOpaque` also didn't really change anything.
By the way I found another oddity with the Aero behavior, I've added it to my question. It looks more and more like one can't do it together with swing.

Comment: What didn't work about `setLayersOpaque`?  I remember trying to tab back and forth from it and that worked.

Comment: @Daniel: Also give it a try disabling DirectDraw and enabling openGL: `-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true`.

Comment: Ah, enabling OpenGL did the trick, I didn't do that before. Now I just have to get rid of this glitchy drawing.