# Customized Title Bar

Tags: java, windows, swing, titlebar

Customized Title Bar

More and more, professional software are customizing their title bars, whether it be, custom buttons or switchable tabs.
Software that I know of:

- MS Office 2010
- Paint.NET
- Firefox
- Etc.

I would like to know how this can be accomplished using java, and the windows Look And Feel.

Google Solutions:

- Hide the title bar and recreate it from scratch. (.setUndecorated(true);)
- Substance Look and Feel has some way of accomplishing title bar customization.

However these solutions don’t provide the desired effect. There has to be a way, this way might not be easy but one must exist. If I have to combine java with some other programming language, so be it, as long as I can accomplish my goal.

Here, is a link to a post of mine under a different username that I was able to accomplish with the .setUndecorated(true); method. However redrawing the entire title bar is tedious, and I couldn’t get it exactly right. Especially the blur effect.

Please any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

[Java-Forums Post](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/50805-customized-title-bar.html#post243459)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx i found a solution, using jni and the tutorial found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and [Disable Background drawing in JFrame in order to properly display Aero (DWM) effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979800/disable-background-drawing-in-jframe-in-order-to-properly-display-aero-dwm-eff)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Falls under LookAndFeel, UIComponent. Best you delve the sources of some Look&Feel for some code snippet. I do not expect an other answer, because not many people will go so far for a customized theme.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I find it highly unlikely that no one has attempted to do this in java, as tutorials are available for vb, c# and c++. I think I’ll hold on a while longer maybe someone has done something similar.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I found this link, this is what i want, however i'm struggeling to implement this in java. i know i should use the jni framework, but i am finding this to be a bit to difficult.